# Complex SOQL query (2 children, same parent)

Tags: soql

I have the following structure:
[image]

How do I get all Document Actions through Document Config by Document Id. Is this even possible in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

```
String documentId; 
List<Document_Actions__c> documentActions = new List<Document_Actions__c>();
for(Document_Config__c dc : [Select id, (select id, name from Document_Actions__r) from Document_Config__c  where Document__c =:documentId] ) {
     documentActions.addAll(dc.Document_Actions__r);
}
System.debug(documentActions);`
```

Something like this should work!
Query will depends on yours api names